# Snappy names for a ReferenceType value and a ValueType value

Tags: c#, naming

I have 2 classes. One handles a ReferenceType value, another does the same on a ValueType value. This is the only difference, but it is important. I am struggling to find a decent name for each class:

- ReferenceTypeValueHandler and ValueTypeValueHandler?

Neah, ValueTypeValue sounds confusing.

- ClassValueHandler and StructValueHandler?

I shouldn't use "Class" in a name of a class, should I?

- NullableValueHandler and NonNullableValueHandler?

"Nullable" is already used for nullable value types (Nullable<>)

- HeapValueHandler and StackValueHandler?

That's dumb. Exploiting the fact that reference type values are stored in the heap and value type values are in the stack, who cares? Also "Stack" is confusing implying it has something to do with a stack.

Any more ideas?

**Update:**

Some people suggest I should explain the purpose of the class. Well, although I don't think it's important, here it is: I am working on a XML to entity deserializer. I use XmlReader to take advantage of the streamline reading rather then working with DOM. As I read XML I build entities. Some entities are just wrappers for some other ones. These wrappers can take either a single entity or a collection (enumerable) of entities. Speaking of those which take a single entity, this entity has to be provided and it has to be provided exactly one time. If XML doesn't have it, it's a problem. If XML has more than 1 it's a problem too. So for keeping and ensuring that the entity is provided exactly one time I have a class `ValueKeeper<TValue>`. It has 2 methods `TakeValue(TValue value)` and `TValue ClaimValue()`. The TakeValue methods takes the value and checks if there is already a value provided before, if so it throws the exception with appropriate details. The ClaimValue method is called once the reading of the wrapper XML is finished and the wrapper entity has to be created over the scraped value, this method checks whether there is a value that was received via the TakeValue method, if so
it just returns that value, if no, then it throws the exception. Now, the problem is that for reference type values I am using comparison to NULL in order to see if the value was provided. In order to make such comparison possible there must be a generic constraint on the TValue type parameter: `where TValue: class`. Having this constraint in place I cannot use this class for value type values. So I need another class that does the same, but operates on values `where TValue: struct` using a `Nullable<TValue>` field to keep either provided or not-yet provided value. Now, with 2 classes I cannot go along just with ValueKeeper, I need one name for the reference type and another for the value type value. Here is where the question comes up. I need a way to express this subtle difference. But again, it's not important what the class does, what's important is to find appropriate way to put this difference clear.

Comment: It might be helpful to further describe the purpose of the class.

Comment: the purpose of a class is literally to keep that value and make sure it was provided. It's not actually important, the rest of the name of a class can be anything, what's important is reflect what sort of values the class operates on.

Comment: Hi again, @bonomo, have you considered using Equals(valueObject, default(TValue)) instead of valueObject == null? There is no need for making a difference between reference and value types...

Comment: Well, you say use Equals, Equals of what? Secondly default(Int32) is 0 that is a legit number value, so it will tell me that there is no value while there was one but it happen to be 0.

Comment: I mean of course I can come up with a single class solution, it can be just a flag that is set when the value is provided, all deductions can be made by checking that flag instead of the value, but it doesn't eliminate the question for similar problems

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't agree that the rest of the class name is not important. You want to make your code speak for itself and to make it easy for the reader to understand the concepts you had in mind when designing the classes/structs. The class names you suggest would give me no idea of what the class is actually doing. I suggest to search for more concrete names: How is the value being handled? What value?

How do struct and class values differ from each other apart from that one is a class and the other one a struct? There must be some more difference because otherwise it wouldn't make sense to have the same thing as a struct and as a class (DRY).

If it's a very abstract operation you perform, try to search for the pattern, or a general name for a concept. To keep the value and make sure it was provided sounds a bit like a caching mechanism?

Secondly, your facing a semantic issue here: what is the term which subsumes 'values' of value types and 'values' of reference types. We could simply ask the inheritance chain of the .NET framework here and call it both an **object**.

So, in this case, something like `CacheForValueTypeObjects` and `CacheForReferenceTypeObjects` could work. I don't know whether cache expresses the purpose well, but if not, I would try to search for a term which best describes the 'final' purpose of the class, the reason why its there.

I bet you didn't think 'Well, what I really need now is a ValueTypeValueHandler!'. There was something more to it. ;) I like this kind of questions, thanks!

Comment: I just updated the question. CacheForValueTypeObjects sounds ok, I might consider it, thank you.